# How can I want to convert a javax.activation.DataHandler object to byte array

Tags: nio, datahandler

I want to convert a javax.activation.DataHandler object to byte array. What is the best way to do it. Is it possible to use nio package for same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler();
InputStream dataHandler = file.getInputStream();
byte[] arrayByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(dataHandler);
```